# Can entangle be used in Alpine store (Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$wire'))?

Tags: laravel-livewire, alpine.js

According to the livewire docs, Alpine data can contain the @entangle which syncs up alpine data and livewire properties:

`<div x-data="{ open: @entangle('showDropdown') }">`

Can an Alpine JS store contain a reference to an entangled variable? For example:

```
    document.addEventListener('alpine:init', function () {
        Alpine.store('currentPage', {
            currentState: @js($currentState),
            selectedProjectId: @entangle('selectedProjectId')
        }
    }
```

Normally (without any @entangle present), with current state I can access it using: `this.$store.currentPage.currentState`

However, with @entangle, when I try to access the store like I manage to do with currentState, I get the following message:

`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$wire')`

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a way to write to sync a store directly with `@entangle`, but it's possible to use `$watch` to send information to the store from Livewire:

```html
<div x-data="{
    init() {
        $watch('messages', messages => messages.forEach(message => $store.messageManager.addMessage(message)))
    },
    messages: @entangle('messages')
}">
    <template x-for="message, index in $store.messageManager.messages">
        <span x-html="JSON.stringify(message, index)"></span>
    </template>
</div>
<script>
    document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
        Alpine.store('messageManager', {
            messages: [],

            addMessage(message) {
                this.messages.push(message)
            },

            deleteMessage(index) {
                this.messages.splice(index, 1)
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

As `messages` is entangled with Livewire, the `$watch` will automatically be called whenever there is something updated from Livewire. This will then call the store and write its messages there.